# cloud-init vs. kickstart vs. preseed

Tags: preseed, cloud-init, kickstart

What is the difference between all those automation features? I found three of them so far:

- cloud-init
- kickstart
- preseeding

Is one of these methods outdated maybe?

Comment: A detailed answer would be the size of a whole book, which suggests that your question may be too broad.

Comment: Well, give it a try... most book can described in one or two sentences.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like cloud-init is for post-installation configuration, in the cloud, whereas the others are for unattended installation from ISO/CD installation media, or PXE boot installation.

If there is something that you can only do easily during the installation phase, then you likely need kickstart or preseed.

This table is probably very incomplete, please anyone feel free to edit:

| System | Docs | Description | Distro | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cloud-init | https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html | "multi-distribution method for cross-platform cloud instance initialisation" | multi | Post OS installation |
| kickstart | https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-kickstart-installations#sect-kickstart-introduction | "Kickstart installations offer a means to automate the installation process, either partially or fully. Kickstart files contain answers to all questions normally asked by the installation program, such as what time zone you want the system to use, how the drives should be partitioned, or which packages should be installed." | Red Hat distros | During installation |
| preseed | https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed#Preseeding_d-i | "Preseeding provides a way to set answers to questions asked during the installation process, without having to manually enter the answers while the installation is running." | Debian (Ubuntu depreciated support) | During installation |
| autoinstall | https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall | "Since version 20.04, the server installer supports automated installation mode (autoinstallation for short). You might also know this feature as unattended, hands-off, or preseeded installation." | Ubuntu Server >=20.04 | During installation |
| Fully Automatic Installation | https://wiki.fai-project.org/ | "FAI is a tool for fully automatic installation of Debian and other Linux Distributions via network, custom install CD, or into a chroot environment. " | Linux variants | During installation |